# Rails group_by id and group created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, group-by

I have a model call `GcMission`

it contains `gamecharacter_id`, `mission_id` and of course `created_at`. 
Now I need to group_by `gamecharacter_id`, and then group the `created_at` to see how many `mission_id` per day.

I assum the result will be like

```
{
  69 => {
    '2017-08-18' => 1
  },
  75 => {
    '2017-08-18' => 2
  },
  78 => {
    '2017-08-18' => 1,
    '2017-08-19' => 1,
  }
}
```

But I am stuck at that.

Here is what I've written.

```
GcMission.select('gamecharacter_id, mission_id, created_at').where(mission_id: assign_mission_ids).where('finish_counter >= 1').group_by{|a| a.gamecharacter_id}
```

And the result is like

```
{
    69 => [
        [0] #<GcMission:0x007ff6c6a53650> {
            :gamecharacter_id => 69,
                  :mission_id => 3,
                  :created_at => Tue, 18 Apr 2017 03:20:36 UTC +00:00
        }
    ],
    75 => [
        [0] #<GcMission:0x007ff6c6a52d18> {
            :gamecharacter_id => 75,
                  :mission_id => 3,
                  :created_at => Tue, 18 Apr 2017 06:38:27 UTC +00:00
        },
        [1] #<GcMission:0x007ff6c6a52408> {
            :gamecharacter_id => 75,
                  :mission_id => 4,
                  :created_at => Tue, 18 Apr 2017 07:55:40 UTC +00:00
        }
    ],
    78 => [
        [0] #<GcMission:0x007ff6c6a51be8> {
            :gamecharacter_id => 78,
                  :mission_id => 3,
                  :created_at => Tue, 18 Apr 2017 17:29:24 UTC +00:00
        },
        [1] #<GcMission:0x007ff6c6a51580> {
            :gamecharacter_id => 78,
                  :mission_id => 4,
                  :created_at => Wed, 19 Apr 2017 03:20:31 UTC +00:00
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Following

```
gc_missions = GcMission.select("gamecharacter_id, DATE(created_at) AS date,
                                COUNT(mission_id) AS mission_count")
                       .group('gamecharacter_id, date')
```

If you want count of unique mission_id per gamecharacter_id per day use
`COUNT(DISTINCT(mission_id))`

You may like to verify using following code

```
gc_missions.each {|gc| puts "#{gc.gamecharacter_id}, #{gc.date}, #{gc.mission_count}"}
```

Comment: The first one seems fails, the result is here https://gist.github.com/fifiteen82726/4a3d2425b87c4a357e17bb5b6140f687